# Which one to choose mysql 32bit or mysql 64 bit?

Tags: mysql, windows-xp

I wanted to install mysql for trying hibernate.

Which one should I install, mysql 32 bit or mysql 64bit?

Please let me know if there is any operational differences between them?

I want to install it on windows xp.

Thanks,
-Uday

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 64 bit version of XP? Remember 32bit systems have a 4GB limit. Google for many discussions and benchmarks on 32vs64bit performance and limitations.

Comment: Ok, my OS is 32 bit version.. So I'll go for 32bit mysql. I'll google about the performance and limitations thanks:)

Comment: @user707724 if you have a 32bit OS you can't run 64bit binaries, so 32bit it is.